# Encoding text file to appear on IBM Mainframe

Tags: c#, c++, encoding, mainframe

I have a C++ program that sends data via FTP via ASCII mode to an IBM Mainframe.  I am now doing this via C#.

When it gets there and viewed the file looks like garbage.

I cannot see anything in the C++ code that does anything special to encode the file into something like EPCDIC.  When the C++ files are sent they are viewed ok.  The only thing I see different is \015 & \012 for line feeds whereas C# is using \r\n.

Would these characters have an effect and if so how can I get my C# app to use \015?

Do I have to do any special encoding to make it appear ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you should indeed be using an EBCDIC encoding, and then probably transferring the text in binary. I have an [EBCDIC encoding class](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/ebcdic/) you can use, should you wish.

Note that `\015\012` *is* `\r\n` - they're characters 13 and 10 in decimal, just different ways of representing them. If you think the C++ code really *is* producing the same files as C#, compare two files which *should* be the same in a binary file editor.

Comment: Your class does not work both ways. I tried converting ASCII to EBSDCI and back again and they ASCII is garbage

Comment: That suggests you weren't using it properly. It definitely *does* work both ways. Please show some code where it's failing, or mail me with it.

Comment: I mailed you at skeet at pobox.com

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the TYPE TEXT instead of TYPE BINARY command before you transfer the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are truly sending the files in ASCII mode, then the mainframe itself will convert that to EBCDIC (it's receiver-makes-good).

The fact that you're getting apparent garbage at the mainframe end, and character codes `\015` and `\012` (which are `CR` and `LF` respectively) means that you're *not* transferring in ASCII mode.

As an aside, the ISPF editor has been able to view ASCII data sets for quite a few versions now. Open up the file and enter the commands `source ascii` and `lf`.

The first renders converts the characters from ASCII to EBCDIC so you can see what they are, the second goes through and pads out "lines" so that linefeed markers are replaced with enough spaces to reach the record length.

Invaluable commands when dealing with mixed-encoding environments, which is where I do a lot of my work.